# SetAllDirty() not working at runtime in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

**Edit:**

After doing a little more debugging I found that it doesn't work only when I start the game and have the panel/canvas that it sits on disabled. If I have the panel/canvas enabled the whole time then it redraws correctly. However, this obviously isn't a proper solution because I can't show the results before the end of the quiz. I need the panel to be disabled so that I can show it later after the end of the quiz.**Is there a reason this is happening? How can I fix this?**

**End Edit**

So I found a script on GitHub that basically creates a UI polygon. It works great in the Editor, however, I want to modify it at runtime. From everything I read all I need to do is call the method `SetAllDirty()` and it will update the MaskableGraphic and Redraw it. However, whenever I call it, nothing happens.  `SetVerticesDirty()` also did not work. Can someone see where I am going wrong here.

All I am doing is calling `DrawPolygon` and giving it `4 sides`, and passing a `float[5]` I modified it so that right after I finish setting up my new variables I call `SetAllDirty()`

Something like this:

```
public void DrawPolygon(int _sides, float[] _VerticesDistances)
{
    sides = _sides;
    VerticesDistances = _VerticesDistances;
    rotation = 0;
    SetAllDirty();
}
```

Like I said, it works fine in the editor(not runtime), and I am also getting all the values passed to the script correctly(during runtime), but it is not redrawing. As soon as I manipulate something in the inspector it will redraw to the correct shape.

The rest of the script is posted here:

https://github.com/CiaccoDavide/Unity-UI-Polygon/blob/master/UIPolygon.cs

This is the method that I call `DrawPolygon` from on a Manager script. I see in the log that it prints out the statement, Quiz has ended.

```
void EndQuiz()
{
    Debug.Log("Quiz has ended.");
    QuizPanel.SetActive(false);
    ResultsPanel.SetActive(true);

    float[] Vertices = new float[5] { score1, score2, score3, score4, score1};

    resultsPolygon.DrawPolygon(4, Vertices);

}
```

Comment: Maybe try the Rebuild function

Comment: @BasilePerrenoud Is there a certain `CanvasUpdate` parameter I need to pass in?

Comment: I don't know, I just suggested this after reading [the doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.MaskableGraphic.html)

Comment: Go from here https://github.com/tenpn/unity3d-ui/blob/master/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/MaskableGraphic.cs.  I think Basile is on the right track but I think if you look at the UNITY_EDITOR section, it's all about the Material.  You might have to set the `Material` dirty.

Comment: @jiveturkey I have edited the question to better reflect the problem that is occurring.